# How to keep CMake from destroying PyDev configuration in Eclipse project

Tags: python, eclipse, cmake

I'm developing a project using CMake that involves a large number of Python scripts. As part of my workflow, I'm generating Eclipse projects from the CMake files, and then using PyDev within Eclipse to edit and test the scripts.

One problem that I have, however, is that each time modify CMakeLists.txt, it regenerates the Eclipse project which overwrites any PyDev configuration (PYTHONPATH, Python Nature, Project References, etc) that I have set.

What I'd like to do is either of the following:

1) Somehow add the PyDev configuration to my CMakeLists.txt so that it is included in the generated project.

2) Have some command-line tool that runs after CMake that modifies the project to include the PyDev stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking into the same problem for a while now, and I've finally found the solution. It appears that in CMake 3.0+, they've introduced a global property called `ECLIPSE_EXTRA_NATURES`, that can be used for this purpose. Just include the following line in your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set_property(GLOBAL APPEND 
  PROPERTY ECLIPSE_EXTRA_NATURES "org.python.pydev.pythonNature")
```

And run cmake (as usual):

```
cmake <Folder_Containing_CMakeLists.txt> -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
```

You'll now see that the generated `.project` file contains the needed `<nature>` element.